# What causes wtmp to be cleared?

Tags: security, logs, last, maintenance, wtmp

I noticed that on one of my machines the `last` command returned nothing. I determined the cause of this to be an empty `/var/log/wtmp` file. What would cause this to be empty? I assume the "tmp" means temporary, but what and where decides how temporary this log file is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/var/log/wtmp` is usually rotated (or just cleared) by a monthly cron job, or with a config file in `/etc/logrotate.d/`

For example: on my Debian system, all the lines in `/etc/logrotate.d/wtmp` are commented out, but `/etc/cron.monthly/acct` (from the `acct` GNU Accounting Utilities package) rotates it and generates a monthly report (`/var/log/wtmp.report`).

Check to see if you have `/var/log/wtmp.1`, `/var/log/wtmp.2`, etc.  Possibly compressed with `.gz` filename extensions.

You can use `last`'s `-f` option to view the records in other wtmp files.  e.g.

```
last -f /var/log/wtmp.1
```

From `man last`:

> `-f`, `--file file`
>
> Tell last to use a specific file instead of `/var/log/wtmp`.
> The `--file` option can be given multiple times, and all of
> the specified files will be processed.

BTW, `last -f` can't read a compressed `wtmp` file.  If it's compressed, you'll have to `gunzip` it first.